# Find an element by Xpath which contains text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

This works fine if I search for a single string:

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'About us')]"));
```

But could I have an **or** statement like in the example below?

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'About us' or 'about us')]"));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

say `or` between two calls of `contains` function

```
//a[contains(text(), 'About us') or contains(text(), 'about us')]
```

or use `translate` function to make xpath case insensitive

```
//a[contains(translate(text(), 'ABOUTS', 'abouts'), 'about us')]
```

Comment: can be a *little bit* simplified to : `translate(text(), 'ABOUTS', 'abouts')`

Comment: @har07 thanks. Specially looked up the repeating letters and missed anyway

Answer (score 1):

Below satisfies your requirement:

```
//a[contains(., 'About us') or contains(., 'about us')]
```

Refer:- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-to-find-element-using-contains-in-xpath for more details.