# How to get text of element that is not inside html tag using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html and I want to get text "Conference USA"

```
<li class="list-unstyled" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <input id="account" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="101" name="account" 
    style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/> Conference USA                                 
</li>
```

Comment: <li class="list-unstyled" style="background-color: transparent;">
   <input id="account" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="101" name="account" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
                            Conference USA                                 
<ul>
</li>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by Xpath which contains text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674093/find-element-by-xpath-which-contains-text)

Comment: There are many questions like this one. Please do a search of SO or just google the question and you will find many answers that you can try.

Comment: Do you want to get text or locate input element by that text???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question and provided comments it's not clear what you want actually.

So if you want `li` element with using text **Conference USA** try as below :-

```
WebElement liElement = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//li[contains(.,'Conference USA')]"));
```

or if you want `input` element with using text **Conference USA** try as below :-

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//li[contains(.,'Conference USA')]/input"));
```

or if you want text **Conference USA** of `li` element try as below :-

```
string text = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//li[./input[@type = 'checkbox' and @value='101']]")).Text;
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to uniquely locate `li` and `getText()` should work. For example in `java` it will look like:

```
String accountName = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[./input[@id='account']]")).getText();
```

**EDIT** `c#`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//li[./input[@id='account']]")).Text;
```

Comment: Id= account is not unique in this case and I actually want to select li on the basis of text

Comment: what is your problem? do you want to get text or locate an element using known text? if you have unique and known value you can write .//li[./input[@value=value]]

Comment: i want to get text, but as you can see,  that text is not inside "input" tag and that the reason I am not able to get that text. I am trying to locate that element "input" element using this text.

Comment: Thanks for your time though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting "innerHTML" attribute from the li webelement like below, I had same situation earlier and it worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'list-unstyled')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```